# Can I change a Thumbnail image without having to click on it (change it by code)?

Tags: python, scripting, add-on, source-code

I'm creating an Addon for Blender 2.8 where use a thumbnail panel:
[image]

Here is my code:

```
import bpy
from bpy.types import Panel, EnumProperty, WindowManager
import bpy.utils.previews
import os

class DemoPanel(bpy.types.Panel):
    bl_idname = 'TIME_PT_demo'
    bl_label = 'DEMO'
    bl_space_type = "PROPERTIES"
    bl_region_type = "WINDOW"
    bl_description = "Tooltip description"
    bl_context = "object"

    def draw(self, context):
        layout = self.layout        

        wm = context.window_manager
        row = layout.row()

        row.template_icon_view(context.scene, "my_thumbnails")

        row = layout.row()
        row.label(text="You selected: " + bpy.context.scene.my_thumbnails)


preview_collections = {}

def generate_previews():
    pcoll = preview_collections["thumbnail_previews"]
    image_location = pcoll.images_location
    VALID_EXTENSIONS = ('.png', '.jpg')

    enum_items = []

    #generate thumbnails
    for i, image in enumerate(os.listdir(image_location)):
        if image.endswith(VALID_EXTENSIONS):
            filepath = os.path.join(image_location, image)
            thumb = pcoll.load(filepath, filepath, 'IMAGE')
            enum_items.append((image, image, "", thumb.icon_id, i))

    return enum_items



def register():  
    from bpy.types import Scene
    from bpy.props import StringProperty, EnumProperty  
    pcoll = bpy.utils.previews.new()

    pcoll.images_location = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), "images")

    preview_collections["thumbnail_previews"] = pcoll

    bpy.types.Scene.my_thumbnails = EnumProperty(
        items=generate_previews(),
    )       

    bpy.utils.register_class(DemoPanel)
```

But when the component is generated I can't set by code what image I want to appear in the thumbnail. I would like to know if is there a way to change in code what images I want to show in the thumbnail without having to click on the panel and selecting the image.

I also tried to dig into the C++ code from the source code but I din't find the definition of the `template_icon_view` function. Only some header files with it.

My objective here is to emulate an animated gif changing the thumbnail with a sequence of several similar images.

Comment: If in blender text editor you ctl-A select all and hit tab (indent all 1 right) then copy it will be formatted correctly when pasted here. That is all a code block requires one extra tab right.  Please fix.

Comment: @batFINGER I selected all, pressed TAB, copy and pasted here. Is it okay now?